# Read ByteArray from Javascript in Flex AS function

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, externalinterface

I need to pass ByteArray from Javascript function to Flex Actionscript function. 
Have tried using the below JS:

```
function deviceResp(s){ 
    var obj = document.getElementById('smera');
    obj.deviceRespFx(s);    
}
```

My AS function :

```
public function imageRespFxs(value:String):void{
    Alert.show(value.length);
}
```

EDIT:
Callback Function is loaded on "**creationComplete**"

```
   public function initDevice():void{                  
                               ExternalInterface.addCallback("deviceRespFx",imageRespFxs);

        }
```

As the above method is inturn converting a byte array to a String so there is a loss of data, could any one please assist on how to pass a Byte Array from JS to AS function.

Comment: You need to show where you set the callback in AS3 (`ExternalInterface.addCallback("deviceRespFX",imageRespFxs);`)

Comment: What is *wrong* with what you've got? Is the Alert not showing? Alert not showing the length you expect?

Comment: Hi Sam, have edited and updated the call for callback, Am able to get the response in my AS function but the problem here is to pass byte array from JS to AS.As the ExternalInterface.call isnt allowing input variable as ByteArray

Comment: Yes the length of variable 's' in JS function is 400 and in AS function it is only 15

Comment: Is the byte array originally a string? Is there a null/0 byte in the middle that's breaking the translation to a string?

Comment: No sam, Byte Array isnt a String Originally it is a Image.

Comment: Why aren't you receiving it as a ByteArray then?

Comment: If I change this function public function imageRespFxs(value:String):void{
    Alert.show(value.length);
}
 value to ByteArray I cannot able to call the AS function sam.

Comment: Can you base64 encode/decode the image? Your issue is that there are nulls found in the image, and when it converts to a string it breaks on the first null.

Comment: Hi Sam, Have tried to base64 encode my byte array using  new Base64().encodeBase64String(imageBuffer); but for strange it is unable to encode the byte array.

Comment: I'm sorry, if that's not working, I'm not sure how to help you. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Sam, Have sorted out the issue, it was with Charset have to use "Cp1252" while creating a String and send it to Flex AS function and at the recieving end have converted the String back to ByteArray using writeMultiByte(str,"Cp1252"); Does this approach leads to any data loss? Kindly share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All thanks to Sam DeHaan,

Have finally managed to get it working with Base64 as hinted by Sam comments.

here is the peice of code might be helpful for others:

Firstly in my Java Code I convert the Image into Base64 String like this :

```
  private String convertBase64String(BufferedImage image){

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Base64OutputStream bi64 = new Base64OutputStream(baos);
    try{
    ImageIO.write(imgRegistration1, "png",bi64);
    baos.flush();               
    String data = baos.toString("UTF-8");
    return data;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

and I send this to FLex AS method and Decode the Same like this:

```
  import mx.utils.Base64Decoder;
  private var base64Dec:Base64Decoder;
  public function imageRespFxs(value:String):void{                
    var byteArr:ByteArray;
            base64Dec = new Base64Decoder();
            base64Dec.decode(value);
            byteArr = base64Dec.toByteArray();
            imgId.load(byteArr);

        }
```

Thanks